# MPC8xx using watchdog with uboot and linux

Tags: linux, powerpc, watchdog, u-boot

I have an embedded platform with a powerpc MPC875 CPU running with uboot and linux 3.2. I'd like to use the watchdog feature of this cpu. My problem is that the watchdog timed out before linux starts the watchdog driver.

My CPU clock frequency is 131MHz which turns that my watchdog has a max timeout of ~1 secondes (using prescaler). The watchdog is per default, after a hard reset enabled and can be only once configured, therefore uboot will configure it and will kick it periodically.
Uboot will kick the watchdog just before starting the linux kernel.

Then the kernel doesn't have the time to load the watchdog driver, which will take over uboot to kick the dog, before the watchdog times out!

The watchdog driver in linux is compiled in and not as a module to be able to be loaded earlier. It will be loaded after being detected from the flat device tree.

Is there any other way to start the linux watchdog driver earlier, to avoid watchdog to times out ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Brice

Comment: This sounds like quite the fun little problem :-)

Comment: Is it possible to disable watchdog by default and enable it by software after boot?

Comment: No it is unfortunately not possible to disable the watchdog by default, it comes always up by default and needs to be either disable or feed up really early :-( I have an other device with another CPU (MPC83xx) and on this one I could disable the watchdog by default and enable it quite late in the boot procedure. I did not find such feature on MPC875 :-(

Comment: I also use MPC875, but ended up telling UBoot not to enable the hardware watchdog (via `#undef CONFIG_WATCHDOG`) and am using the linux software watchdog instead

Comment: Use an extended timeout during boot.  Minimize the Linux boot time, by using modules and an initramfs (having other benefits).  Alter the code in *init/main.c* to do the kicks.